# Using Angular2 in a classic CMS

Tags: angular, content-management-system, angular2-template

I'm currently diving into Angular2 and see a lot of potential in it.

Nevertheless I'm asking myself, if Angular2 is a good candidate for classic frontend development in CMS projects, where the content and content structure comes from the editor and therefore from the server.

I've read a lot about the Angular2 templating system.
Now to my question:

You initiate an Angular2 app by adding the AppComponents selector tag into the DOM, like so:

```
<body>
  <my-app>
    Loading...
  </my-app>
</body>
```

Now all the apps content is somewhere hidden in the Angular2 templates for all the components.

In the real world a CMS would output all the content information within the DOM, like so:

```
<body>
  <my-app>
    <editor-content>
      <h1>Some articles heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <a href="#">A fancy link</a>
    </editor-content>
  </my-app>
</body>
```

When Angular2 starts, all the initial content is like thrown away and replaced by the template defined in AppComponent.

How can I tell AppComponent, that it should initialize using the content from the CMS?
Is there even a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the-box you can't.

I'd suggest that you have your CMS put all the relevant data in a global variable. You could consume that in a service.

```
<head>
  <script> <!-- this could go in the body, too. As long as it's loaded before angular -->
    window.myCMSData = JSON.parse(jsonEncodedDataFromCMS);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
</body>
```

service:

```
@Injectable()
export class CMSDataService{
  data: any; //or whichever type your data is.

  constructor(){
    this.data = window.myCMSData;
  }
}
```

Once you have moved the data into an angular2 service everything's business as usual.

-

This could be done more elegantly by using a REST API, but this approach will work fine and you won't need to struggle with additional setup.